# Radio Button INPUT not sending the input to the PHP code

Tags: php, forms, post, radio-button

The code is given below shows the errors :

```
<div class="field form-inline radio">
<form method="post" action="">
<div>
<label><input type="radio" name="eatable" value="fruit_in"/> Fruit</label>
</div>  
<div>
<label><input type="radio" name="eatable" value="vegetable_in"/> Vegetable</label>
</div>  
<div>
<label><input type="radio" name="eatable" value="bread_in"/> Bread</label>
</div>  
<div>
<label><input type="radio" name="eatable" value="milk_in"/> Milk</label>
</div>
</form> <?php 
$veg = $_POST['eatable']?>
```

**Please can anyone tell what is the problem in the code ?**
The Error says that :
  Notice: Undefined index: eatable in C:\xampp\htdocs\k\upload.php on line 250

Comment: are these all in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notice: Undefined index** is caused, due to `$_POST` doesn't have index `eatable`, as your form is not yet posted.

You can do something like:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['eatable'])){
$veg = $_POST['eatable'];
} ?>
```

Comment: That was a mistake while writing the question(formatting). What you corrected is the actual code. This is not working

Answer (score 0):

**Modify tour code like**..

```
<form method="post" action="" name="items"><div><label><input type="radio" name="eatable" value="fruit_in" <?php if($_POST[eatable=="fruit_in"]) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> /> Fruit</label>
</div>  
<div>
<label><input type="radio" name="eatable" value="vegetable_in" <?php if($_POST[eatable=="vegetable_in"]) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> /> Vegetable</label>
</div>  
<div>
<label><input type="radio" name="eatable" value="bread_in" <?php if($_POST[eatable=="bread_in"]) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> /> Bread</label>
</div>  
<div>
<label><input type="radio" name="eatable" value="milk_in" <?php if($_POST[eatable=="milk_in"]) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> /> Milk</label>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking the value to be send to php code on 'submit' form use

> $_POST['eatable'];

else you can use "ajax" on click event

Answer (score 0):

the problem is simply because 'eatable' is not yet define when you open the file. 'eatable' will only be define once you submit the form, so change it to..

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST['eatable'])){
     $veg = $_POST['eatable']
   }
?>
```

also on your form, you need to add a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="eatable" value="fruit_in"/> Fruit</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="eatable" value="vegetable_in"/> Vegetable</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="eatable" value="bread_in"/> Bread</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="eatable" value="milk_in"/> Milk</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //php code goes here.
    //this will only run when only submit button clicked.
    $veg = $_POST['eatable'];
}
```